# round adds unwanted decimals

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

When I am returning my function, the answers are inconsistent. I am trying to round to .05. 
example: 26.93 -> 26.95
Here is what happens.. What did I do wrong?
Thanks

```
 >>> cashback = (0.05 * round(payment/0.05)) 

 >>> cad_cashier(23,26.93)
 'The change value is: 3.950000000000003'

 >>> cashback = (0.05 * round((payment) / 0.05))
 >>> cad_cashier(23,26.52)
 'The change value is: 3.5'
```

Why does one value work but the other value adds 0003?

Comment: Related: [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455612/364696)

Comment: The conversion from decimal floating point to binary floating point involves some approximation in many cases. A number ending in .5 works perfectly in binary.

Comment: For Python you can use the [`Decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html) to eliminate rounding errors caused by binary arithmetic.

Comment: But python 3 does a good job at rounding floats to n decimals, and binary shifts *2 and /2 won't arm, so `round(2*x,1)/2` could possibly work, even if counting money with float is a dangerous sport with many pitfalls

Comment: Thank you. So I will look up decimal module